# Error Installing Jekyll on OSX (Updated RubyGems)

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, jekyll

I'm trying to install [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/), a simple, blog-aware, static site generator.  When I attempted to run the terminal command `gem install jekyll`, I got this error:

[image: Error installing Jekyll. Failed to build gem native extensions.]

I then tried to update my RubyGems, using the command `sudo gem update --system`.  That didn't work.  Also, I attempted to install using `sudo -s` (as admin).

Hopefully, I don't have to re-install Ruby.  What a headache that would be!

Comment: Have you tried `sudo gem install jekyll`? Btw, installing Ruby via [RVM](https://rvm.io/) seems to be a better way in the first place.

Comment: In your example, you say you use sudo to update ruby, but not to install Jekyll. So use sudo for that too. That has always worked for me.

Comment: I did use sudo to install Jekyll: `sudo -s gem install jekyll`.

Someone on another forum suggested I follow <a href="http://internet-inspired.com/wrote/install-jekyll-in-osx-mavericks/">these</a> steps, and install Jekyll afterward; however, do I absolutely need to install Xcode to successfully install Jekyll?  Never heard that before.

Comment: I have never heard it before either. But I can't really tell, because the most recent version of Xcode is always on my system.

Comment: But it might be true that you need the Xcode command line tools, as the article says.

Answer (score 0):

What version of OS X are you using?

Try this from your shell to install xcode command line tools
`xcode-select --install`

Then launch xcode and agree to the license. Then try again.